# Local dependency not pointing to lib folder when doing import

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

I have a local package that I want to use as a local dependency with this kind of structure:

```
.
├── main-project
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── helper-package <-- symlink to helper-package (below)
│   ├── package.json
│   └── index.ts
└── helper-package
    ├── node_modules
    ├── lib
    │   ├── utils
    │   │   └── parser.js
    │   └── index.js
    ├── src
    │   ├── utils
    │   │   └── parser.ts
    │   └── index.ts
    └── package.json
```

And I want to do my imports like this:

```
import Helper from "helper-package"
import Parser from "helper-package/utils/parser"
```

This is how I'm adding the dependency:

`main-project/package.json`：

```
{ 
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "helper-package": "file:../helper-package",
  } 
}
```

But this results in me having to do my imports like this, which I don't want:

```
import Helper from "helper-package/lib"
import Parser from "helper-package/lib/utils/parser"
```

If instead I do this:

```
"helper-package": "file:../helper-package/lib",
```

... then it complains that `helper-package/lib` doesn't have a package.json. If I copy `helper-package/package.json` to `helper-package/lib`, it works without warnings, but other npm libraries don't have any package.json in their `lib` folder, so I'd like to avoid doing that too... It's silly to be copying the package.json to a subfolder anyway.

How can I set this up properly?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to recreate [npm workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces), which should work for your case.

Comment: That's not it but thanks anyway